# Making UI update when comments are deleted.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react post component with attached comments.

The comments are layed out over three components with a structure like such

```
PaginatedComments (contains array of comments as state) --> Comments (which is a higher order component --> SingleComment (which is each individual comment)
```

Right now i have made a handler in my PaginatedComments
to delete comments from the state

```
deleteCommentHandler = (indexToDelete) =>{
    console.log(this.state.comments)
    this.state.comments.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
    console.log(this.state.comments)
    }
```

with the console.log i succesfully check that the comment is deleted as desired

i then pass the function as a prop, along with the comments as the state:

```
<Comments comments={this.state.comments} clicked={this.deleteCommentHandler} />}
```

In my higher order component the method is passed down through

the higher order component

```
  <ul className="comments">
  {this.props.comments.map(comment =>
    <SingleComment key={comment.id} comment={comment} clicked={this.props.deleteCommentHandler} {...this.props}/>
  )}
</ul>
```

)

then i call the function, with a button, for each comment. I also make a server request, to delete it in the backend.

```
deleteCommentHandler = (id) =>{
  console.log(id);
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  })

  this.commentMapper.deletePostComments(id).then(res =>{ // deletes comment in backend
    this.setState({loading: false})
  });
  let indexToDelete = this.props.comments.findIndex((comment) =>{
    return comment.id === id;
  });
 this.props.clicked(indexToDelete)
 console.log('we are here')
```

however the UI does not render, whenever i click the button?

What is a bit strange, is that with the console log in my deleteCommenthandler it initially logs out an empty object

(From Chrome Dev Tools)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this part of the code

```
deleteCommentHandler = (indexToDelete) =>{
    console.log(this.state.comments)
    this.state.comments.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
    console.log(this.state.commentdirectly
```

You are direclty changing detail in state.

Never change state details directly else changes will not reflect in DOM as `render` was never called.

Always use `this.setState({..})` to update your state values

You can do changes in your `deleteCommentHandler` something like this.

**Note:** Just for reference of how to do changes, code may or may not work

```
deleteCommentHandler = (indexToDelete) =>{
     console.log(this.state.comments)
     var currComments = this.state.comments;
     currComments.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
     this.setState({comments: currComments})
    console.log(this.state.comments)
}
```

Try after doing this change.

Answer (score 1):

You change state here without using setState():

```
this.state.comments.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
```

splice will change the content of comments. so state never changed by this.setState. render() will not be called.